# Validations with ViewModel - MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I am trying to implement both Create and List actions in a single View. I was being suggested to use ViewModel. I am getting the `object reference error`. Also some good example on how to achieve this will help.

My Model Class

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

My View Model Class

```
public class EmployeeVM
{
   public Employee Employee { get; set; }
   public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Create(EmployeeVM emp, string Name)
 {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) //my modelstate is valid even when the value is empty string; it then gives an Object reference not set error
        {
            emp.Employee.Name = Name;

            repository.SaveRole(emp);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(emp);
        }
    }
```

My View

```
@model ERP.Domain.Entity.EmployeeVM

<body>
<div class="jumbotron">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
    {

   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <label>
            Name</label>
        <input id="txtName" type="text" name="Name" class="btn btn-default" />
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee.Name)

        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
    }
</div>
```

Also I was suggested in StackOverflow to go with ViewModel approach if I want to use both Create and List in the same View? Is it the right approach. Some example may help.

Comment: You need to put the `Required` attribute on your view model, not in the model. The view knows nothing about the `Employee` class

Comment: your input type should be this way...<input id="txtName" type="text" name="Employee_Name" class="btn btn-default" />...i think your problem will solve now....

Comment: @DavidG, could you please demonstrate that, like how would i put a `required` attribute on my ViewModel

Comment: @user2281858 You already have one in your model, just do the same for the view model.